# Creating a jQuery Plugin out of jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my problem: I've got this nice [Office Minibar implementation](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2010/05/23/microsoft-office-minibar-jQuery-CSS3.aspx)  which I want to use on my project.  However, I need to apply the Jquery code to dynamically created textarea elements, hence requiring the use of

```
$("#textarea_id").minibar();  //minibar() applies the minibar to the selected textarea element
```

However, i'm at a complete loss on how to do it.  Any help would be great appreciated.  The Minibar coding is fairly simple:

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2010/05/23/microsoft-office-minibar-jQuery-CSS3.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start out reading the [jQuery plugin authoring guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). It does a really good job of walking you through things. If you want to cut to the chase, read the [summary and best practices section](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Summary_and_Best_Practices).

---

Basically, it'll look like this:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.minibar = function () {
        // minibar initialization code here
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) is a great starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree that the [Plugin Authoring tool](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) is a good start.

Also there is a [Jquery Plugin Skeleton](https://github.com/OscarGodson/jQuery-Plugin-Skeleton) that provides a commonly used plugin pattern.

I noticed that in your code you have static ids and markup. It may be better to create these elements dynamically so people that use your plugin don't have to add them and there are no id or class name conflicts.